# Where can I try a locally brewed Porter in London?

Tags: food-and-drink, london, alcohol

One of my favorite beverages back home is a locally brewed [Vanilla Porter](http://web.archive.org/web/20131206202039/http://wichitabrew.com/beers.html).  As the Porter style of beer was invented in London, I was excited to try some local English porters... but in every pub, I've been greeted with confusion and dumbfoundedness when I've asked for a porter. It seems local barmaids have never even *heard* of a Porter.

Surely there's somewhere in London, though, where I can try a locally brewed (ideally on tap) London Porter. Where?

Comment: Have you been going to pubs featured in the Good Beer Guide (or similar), or just wandering into random ones?

Comment: Random ones, essentially. Last night, I went to the pub featuring a salsa class (still quite random, for the purposes of finding a Porter).

Comment: With all the wonderful ales originating in England, I am always surprised that many pubs go to the trouble of having 5 or more different beers on tap only to offer a range of broadly similar industrial pils/lager.

Comment: I've no idea how long they'll have it for, but [The Euston Tap](http://www.eustontap.com/index.php) normally has a porter on tap, and [at present](http://eustontap.wordpress.com) it seems to be [Redemption Fellowship Porter](http://www.redemptionbrewing.co.uk/the-beer/) which is brewed in North London.

Comment: The Euston Tap is also a sub-10 minute walk from where we're doing Friday night's meetup, in case you need a warm up... :)

Comment: @Annoyed: In England if you want ale you go to an alehouse, if you want lager you go to a pub. (Or something along those lines.)

Comment: @hippietrail I don't think that's the way it works. Alehouse is just an older word from the time all beers were ales. Many pubs simply serve a particular brewer's line-up (i.e. one pils, a couple of ales, one cider), which is cool. Others have a wide range of beers, on tap an in bottles (especially those recommended by CAMRA), which is nice too. And a simple bar with one pils on tap is fine by me, I don't demand fancy beers!

Comment: Terminology aside, my point is that establishments that spend money on five “independent” taps to pretend to be fancy and offer a larger choice should not simply carry essentially the same beer from different brands. Even if there was a particular name for it and that was what “pub” means, there is no point to it in my opinion. But since many do it, I guess some people must appreciate that…

Comment: I only know from the one time I visited England and this is what my local friends told me. I often don't like bars and pubs and my friends told me the atmosphere in an alehouse is very different. They took me to one and I found I agreed with them. It is twelve years ago though so I can't recall if it was in London or Sheffield, though I think the latter.

Comment: You'd probably do well to see what the local CAMRA (Camaign for real Ale) recommend:
[http://www.camralondon.org.uk/](http://www.camralondon.org.uk/)

Comment: @hippietrail I actually remember a wonderful place in Sheffield and indeed the atmosphere was quite different. It's just the sharp distinction between “alehouse” and “pub” I am unsure about. I am not a native English speaker but as an example CAMRA is happy to name good “alehouses” as their “pub of the year”.

Comment: Hmm if it was in Sheffield then I may have gone with friends who weren't native English speakers either since those friends were German ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Porter is currently an unfashionable beer style, as far as the *mainstream* goes, so in the larger 'chain' pubs you'd be unlikely to find one.

However, that's not to say there's none to be found! Your first step is to find the right kind of pub, for which there are many resources available; the best physical one I would say would be CAMRA's Good Beer Guide (bookshops everywhere). Online your search terms would be 'real ale', 'craft beer', and of course 'london pub'.

Here are some specific resources which should help:

[Beer in the Evening](http://www.beerintheevening.com/) - general pub reviews

[Fancy a pint](http://www.fancyapint.com/) - pub reviews with an ale-drinking preference

[The GBG pubs of London](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ccaajpa/pubs-listed.html) - but without the commentary that the book itself provides.

Finally, you could always cheat and look in [a supermarket for a bottled version](http://www.fullers.co.uk/rte.asp?id=63) - not as good as the real thing, but consistently a decent pint.

Finally finally, if you're in East London I would personally urge you to try something by the [East London Brewing Company](http://www.eastlondonbrewing.com/try-us.php) - they don't currently do a straight porter, but their mild is worth a special trip, to my mind.

Comment: The Good Beer Guide is also available as an app on a number of mobile platforms, which is a particularly useful way of accessing it.

Comment: Hi! Great answer! Some links are dead though :(